# Replace images by others with javascript

Tags: javascript, image, replace

How can I replace images by others with javascript please ?

I've tried but something is wrong

```js
 if ($(".grimm")) {
   $('.ch').
     html(
       $('.ch').
         html().
         replace('http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/graphicrating/koloria/32/Mail-icon.png',
                 'http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/graphicrating/koloria/32/Mails-icon.png')
   );
 }
```

```html
<div class="grimm">
  <div class="ch">
    <img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/graphicrating/koloria/32/Mail-icon.png" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What is the "*something*" that "*is wrong*"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure to include jQuery, then your fiddle works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/dm9xkmkd/1/

But you can also handle this in one step without involving `replace()` or rewriting large chunks of HTML:

```js
$('.grimm .ch img[src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/graphicrating/koloria/32/Mail-icon.png"]').
  attr('src', 'http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/graphicrating/koloria/32/Mails-icon.png');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="grimm">
  <div class="ch">
    <img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/graphicrating/koloria/32/Mail-icon.png" />
  </div>
</div>
```